# Floating div incorrectly layered

Tags: bug, design

This is happening when you ask questions.

[image]

I reproduced this on a different SE website and with the latest versions of Chrome and Firefox

Comment: It is related to the z-index reshuffle that was done a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah, my bad. Reclosing with the right target. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @Adam, hope this will be fixed because like I said it's really ugly.

Comment: Seeing this (and the "users reached") z-index bug being reported ten times a day is really fun.